# Преобразование unicode в str в Python 2.7

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8, unicode, python-2.7

Есть строка (слово - Истец):

```
s = u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'
```

Как преобразовать ее внормальный вид? smart_bytes, encode и decode не помогают.

Comment: @LinnTroll, нет, не оно, говорю же, нужно преобразовать unocode в строку так, чтобы была в нормальном виде.

Comment: Вы что то делаете не так либо не понимаете что делаете.

Я так понял у вас проблема в этой строке:

    obj = Object(pk=int(obj_s[alias_obj.decode('UTF-8')])) # Ошибка

У вас там ошибка? какая? не может в decode? KeyError? или что?

покажите на этом этапе 

    print alias_obj
    print type(alias_obj)

тогда мы наконец поймем что же у вас за строка. 

а затем покажите 

    print obj_s

и тогда, если со строкой все ок, мы поймем по ней не удается влезть в словарь.

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev: посмотрите на заголовок.

Comment: @jfs Предлагаю перейти в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27697/python--ru-so)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Нет, не помогает, все равно unescape возвращает объект unicode.
Полопатил еще и вот:

```
> a = u'Истец'
> b = 'Истец'
> a.encode('utf-8') == b
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Она и так в нормальном виде.

```
>>> s = u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'
>>> print s
Истец
```

Comment: Только print выводит эту строку правильно, а это - ключ словаря, и python не находит по ключу '\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'

Comment: Должен находить. В ключе не забывайте тоже писать u перед кавычками.

    >>> s = u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'
    >>> d = {s: 100}
    >>> print d[u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446']
    100

Comment: Ключ я вообще не сам задаю, он таким берется в качестве htmlsafe строки и преобразуется к unicode левой либой.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. Покажите код, который у вас не работает.

Comment: Если у вас каким то чудом оказалась строка, не unicode, а str, содержащая \u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446 то привести ее к юникоду можно так:

    '\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'.decode('unicode-escape')

Comment: Шаблонизатор для офисных документов - код функции рендер темплейт тега, позволяющий использовать кириллические символы в контексте (сырая версия):

    def render(self, context):
        if len(self.format_string) == 2:
            bunch = Bunch.objects.get(pk=context['bunch'])

            obj_s = json.loads(bunch.obj_s)
            alias_obj, field = self.format_string[1][1:-1].split('.')
            alias_obj = unescape(alias_obj)  # html-safe в unicode
            obj = Object(pk=int(obj_s[alias_obj.decode('UTF-8')])) # Ошибка
            return obj.fields[field]
        return "NULL"

Comment: это всего лишь код модуля, просто как привести ту строку к виду - "Истец"?

Comment: Чуть выше про unicode-escape гляньте, не оно?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы преобразовать Юникодный текст в последовательсность байтов, можно использовать `encode()` метод:

```
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
```

Скорее всего лучше оставить `s` как есть и работать с Юникодным текстом напрямую. И наоборот, если программа получает текст в виде байт, то необходимо преобразовать их в Юникод как можно скорее.

Answer (score -1):

s = u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'.encode('utf-8')
print s

Answer (score -2):

В начале скрипта вставь строку -

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
print u'\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0446'
Истец
```